# Move Internet Shortcuts From Home Screen to USB

Tags: usb, home-screen-shortcuts

I am attempting to move several Internet shortcuts from my Android Home Screen to a USB memory stick.

I am able to move images and music to and from my USB. But I am unable to find to path to Home Screen in File Manager.

How can I achieve my goal of moving these Internet shortcuts to a USB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Home screens on Android are not represented by file system folders, they are part of the launcher data, and shortcuts are not discrete files like in desktop OSes.

You can't just move them around by copying files like you would on windows.

If you want to move internet shortcuts to a thumbdrive then either export your browser bookmarks to an HTML file, or write them down in a text file instead.

Some launchers also offer the possibility of exporting or backing up settings to a file on the SD card, which may be helpful to move to a thumb drive. I doubt they will allow granular per-shortcut export though

Comment: I was afraid of this. Thank you for your clarification.